# "AssertionError: Thread.__init__() not called" when initializing a subclass of threading.Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to make a program which runs two threads which can be simultaneously interrupted using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The following script is a simplified version of this:

```
import time
import threading

class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def run_once(self):
        print("Controller {} is running once...".format(self.name))

    def run_forever(self):
        while True:
            self.run_once()
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    controller1 = Controller(name="1")
    controller2 = Controller(name="2")
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=controller1.run_forever)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=controller2.run_forever)
    thread1.daemon = True
    thread2.daemon = True
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()


    try:
        while True:
            thread1.join(1)
            thread2.join(1)
            if not thread1.isAlive() or not thread2.isAlive():
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

I'm trying to make the code a bit more DRY by doing the following:

```
import time
import threading

class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def run_once(self):
        print("Controller {} is running once...".format(self.name))

    def run_forever(self):
        while True:
            self.run_once()
            time.sleep(1)

class ThreadController(Controller, threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, target=self.run_forever)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread1 = ThreadController(name="1")
    thread2 = ThreadController(name="2")

    try:
        while True:
            thread1.join(1)
            thread2.join(1)
            if not thread1.isAlive() or not thread2.isAlive():
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

However, when I try to run the latter script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading_test3.py", line 34, in <module>
    thread1 = ThreadController(name="1")
  File "threading_test3.py", line 18, in __init__
    Controller.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "threading_test3.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.name = name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 971, in name
    assert self.__initialized, "Thread.__init__() not called"
AssertionError: Thread.__init__() not called
```

I don't understand why `Thread.__init__()` is not called, because it seems like it is called in the `__init__` of `ThreadController`. What is causing this error?

Comment: Multiple-inheriting from `Controller` and `threading.Thread` is really the wrong way to go here. If you want to reduce code repetition, write a function.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) `If the subclass overrides the constructor, it must make sure to invoke the base class constructor (Thread.__init__()) before doing anything else to the thread.`

Comment: …following up on @CAB's answer: namely, here you initialize `Controller` before `Thread` and that's what generates the exception. Though your approach is still conceptually not the right one, as user2357112 rightfully said.

Comment: By the way, Kurt Peek, your attempt at being DRY, which implies more concise, is 66 lines, while your original code was 64. Adding neither features nor flexibility (rather, removing some). Definitely not the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Thread's init, first;

```
class ThreadController(Controller, threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, target=self.run_forever)
        Controller.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
```